# Group List and Convert to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following List:

```
var products = new List<(int ProductId, int Quantity)>
{
    (10125237,2),
    (7775711,1),    
};
```

And I am grouping the list as follows:

```
var groupedCustomerList = products
    .GroupBy(u => u.ProductId)
    .Select(grp => grp.AsEnumerable());
```

I then pass the grouped list to the following Method:

```
public Builder Products(IEnumerable<(int ProductId, int Quantity)> products)
{
    this.products.AddRange(products);
    return this;
}
```

But when I compile, I get the following error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(int VariantId, int Quantity)>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(int variantId, int quantity)>'

Am I missing something since I have already converted `groupedCustomerList` to an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: you must change the type

Comment: Notice that the error message says you have `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<(int, int)>>` when what was expected was `IEnumerable<(int, int)>`.

Comment: What purpose does the grouping serve? What is `VariantId`?

Comment: .SelectMany(.. should solve

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I am grouping so that i can iterate through a list of products one by one. VariantID is meant to be ProductID, i will updated that

Comment: @spzvtbg SelectMany does work but I am trying to iterate through the list 1 product at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the total quantity by product Id:

```cs
var groupedProductList = products
    .GroupBy(u => u.ProductId)
    .Select(g => (ProductId: g.Key, Quantity: g.Sum(p => p.Quantity)));
```

This is achieved by creating a tuple in the Select-clause. The product Id is the key of the group (since we grouped by this Id). Instead of retrieving a enumeration of products in the group, we sum the quantities of these products.

Note that your original query yields a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<(int, int)>>`, i.e., nested enumerations.

This solution returns a simple enumeration: `IEnumerable<(int ProductId, int Quantity)>` compatible with your builder method.

Answer (score 0):

U can directly pass the list to the function as List already inherits IEnumerable interface.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).